# Installing Windows Server 2008 - RAID - No Drivers Found

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, installation

I'm tring to install Windows Server 2008 on our server (it currently has a beta version on).
I've inserted the dvd, booted into it, and tried to do a new installation

When I come to the screen where you would normally select where to install it, an error message is displayed at the bottom:

> No drivers were found. Click Load Driver to provider a mass stoarage driver for.....

Also, no drives are displayed, so there's nowhere I can install Windows...

The server is configured with RAID 10.
I think I need some kind of RAID driver, but which one do I need?

Comment: any chance of some details? server make/model, same for controllers etc. as it's difficult to help with no real information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are going to need to get the drivers for the RAID controller and supply them to the setup program. Fortunately you are using server 2008 so you can use either a floppy disk, or a USB thumb drive to supply the drivers, assuming your BIOS supports using USB, if it was 2003 you'd be stuck with just a floppy.

When you boot Windows, you will see a message saying "Press F6 to install a third party driver", press F6. Windows will later present you with the option to load you drives. At this point insert your disk or thumb drive, press enter and then select the right driver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I have found a "driver cd" that came with the motherboard - will that be it? Should i copy the files to usb?

Comment: You need to look on that CD and locate the RAID drivers then copy these to USB

Comment: If you are using a built on RAID card then yes.  If the RAID card isn't built on then it'll have it's own CD.